# LESS file structuring for big React applications

Tags: reactjs, webpack

How to structure less styles where there are global mixin files, theme files and individual Component styles.
Importing all global style files in each component style files will duplicate the global styles in each generated css file using extract-text-plugin.

What is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I personally use ITCSS architecture. It works really well in small sized and also large sized projects.

https://www.xfive.co/blog/itcss-scalable-maintainable-css-architecture/

Idea is quite similar to yours but it solves large and complex CSS structure by ordering them in specificity order.